# Jquery image slider with mouse over event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, mouseover

In [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cAsB3/793/), first image automatically slides but each image that i put mouse on them must slide.
I have added `onmouseover` event in html and gave a name to the main function like below but it didn't work.
How can i do jQuery image slider with mouse over?

HTML:

```
<ul onmouseover="imageSlider()" id="exampleSlider">
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x260" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x270" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x280" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
<ul onmouseover="imageSlider()" id="exampleSlider">
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x260" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x270" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x280" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function imageSlider () {

    /* SET PARAMETERS */
    var change_img_time     = 3000; 
    var transition_speed    = 300;

    var simple_slideshow    = $("#exampleSlider"),
        listItems           = simple_slideshow.children('li'),
        listLen             = listItems.length,
        i                   = 0,

    changeList = function () {

        listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
            i += 1;
            if (i === listLen) {
                i = 0;
            }
            listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
        });

    };

    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);

};
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want to happen on mouseover? Since the slider is automatically running, I don't quite get what is the desired effect. And no duplicate IDs in HTML.

Comment: @algoni i want to change these four images with a loop when i mouse over them. I will use changing images as a video preview.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are trying this! try this

```
$('img').mouseenter(function(){ //or you can use hover()
    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: "right" };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 1000;

    $(this).toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/raghuchandrasorab/cAsB3/794/

Comment: i want to change these four images with a loop when i mouse over them. I will use changing images as a video preview.

Answer (score 0):

This will not animate anything until you mouse over the slider, and stops when the mouse leaves the area.

```
$(function () {

/* SET PARAMETERS */
var change_img_time     = 3000; 
var transition_speed    = 300;

var simple_slideshow    = $("#exampleSlider"),
    listItems           = simple_slideshow.children('li'),
    listLen             = listItems.length,
    i                   = 0,
    intervalId  // Generated id for the interval timer

    changeList = function () {

        listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
            i += 1;
            if (i === listLen) {
                i = 0;
            }
            listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
        });

    };

listItems.not(':first').hide();


$('#exampleSlider').on('mouseenter', function() {
    changeList(); // Do this once immediately
    intervalId = setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId); // Stop slider
});;



});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x97a0py5/1/). Note that if you have multiple sliders you need to match by a class name (or anything other than an id) since the id attribute must be unique.